# std::find multiple elements and logical operators

Tags: c++, algorithm, find, operators, logical-operators

I currently have

```
if(std::find(row.begin(), row.end(), 12) != row.end()) {
    std::cout << "12 Found"
}
```

and would like to expand it to do

```
if(std::find(row.begin(), row.end(), 12 && 13 || 18 && 19)  != row.end()) {
    std::cout << "12 and 13 Found or 18 && 19"
}
```

I can obviously do this with multiple if statements but would prefer to do it as quick as possible. Is there anything that will allow me to do this?

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to do. Possibly examples of sequences and desired result.

Comment: If you prefer to do the search as quick as possible, then how about using a non-linear data structure / algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that old-fashioned range iteration will work best, here:

```
bool found12=false;
bool found13=false;

for (const auto &value:row)
{
   if (value == 12)
        found12=true;

   if (value == 13)
        found13=true;

   if (found12 && found13)
        break;
}
```

Lather, rinse, and repeat for 18 & 19.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant, but does the job:

```
std::array<bool, 4> found = {false};
if(std::any_of(v.begin(), v.end(), [&found](int i) 
        {
            if(i == 12) found[0] = true;
            if(i == 13) found[1] = true;
            if(found[0] && found[1]) return true;

            if(i == 18) found[2] = true;
            if(i == 19) found[3] = true;

            if(found[2] && found[3]) return true;
            return false;
        })) 
{
    std::cout << "12 and 13 Found or 18 && 19" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is probably not best suited for this question, but I think it's fun and it could come in handy for something similar:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> row{ 1, 2, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19 };
    std::map<int,bool> m {std::make_pair(12,false), std::make_pair(13,false), std::make_pair(17,false), std::make_pair(18,false) };

    m = std::accumulate(row.begin(), row.end(), m, 
                        [](std::map<int,bool> m, int i) { 
                            auto it = m.find(i); 
                            if (it != m.end()) it->second = true;
                            return m;});

    std::cout << ((m[12] && m[13]) || (m[17] && m[18])) << std::endl;
}
```

Based on the input, it sets map which is filled in according to the requested elements.  Then the logic can be done on the map more easily.
Mind you that since the map is being copied per element, this can never be a performant solution.

---

Improvement by Revolver_Ocelet (faster and cleaner), taken from the link to Corilu in his comment:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    using lookup_t = std::map<int,bool>;
    std::vector<int> row{ 1, 2, 7, 12, 13, 17, 19 };
    lookup_t m {std::make_pair(12,false), std::make_pair(13,false), std::make_pair(17,false), std::make_pair(18,false) };

    std::accumulate(row.begin(), row.end(), std::ref(m),
                        [](lookup_t& m, int i) {
                            auto it = m.find(i);
                            if (it != m.end()) it->second = true;
                            return std::ref(m);});

    std::cout << ((m[12] && m[13]) || (m[17] && m[18])) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You can fix copying by making lambda to take and return reference and pass `reference_wrapper` to the `accumulate`

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: thanks I tried it [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c1a76fb5d335172), but I'll leave the answer for "simplicity".

Comment: just a minor correction, you actually need to return `reference_wrapper` too, or it would assign instead of rebinding: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3db78520ba42d09

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: Nice, I nicked it.